# Paging data for jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, paging

I am trying to load 1K data in a page and showing it with the jquery data table. Because the page is a list of personnel. And end user wants to search for it without any filters.

What is the best solution for requesting 20 data per page not loading all data and letting data table to handle the paging?

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you a lot Rory. As it's obvious I am new and I really searched hard for this solution and when I was writing it no similar question was suggested. I thought maybe someone else had this problem too.

Answer (score -1):

Try this plug-in - [DataTables](https://datatables.net/), I think it has all you need and is quite simple to use.